# Small object argument for multiple factorization systems

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory

Is there something similar to the small object argument, but related to a *chain* of factorization systems on a category $\cal C$?

It is easy to see that one can give a chain of "generating morphisms" $J_1\subseteq \cdots \subseteq J_n$ and obtain a reversed chain passing to the orthogonals
$$
J_1^\perp\supseteq \cdots \supseteq J_n^\perp
$$
If each $J_\alpha$ is a set of morphisms with small co/domains this, using the SOA one time for each $J_\alpha$, entails that there is a chain of factorization systems
$$
\big({}^\perp(J_n^\perp),J_n^\perp \big) \le \cdots \le \big({}^\perp(J_1^\perp),J_1^\perp \big)
$$

Series of Bousfield localizations of a given model category are a natural example of this. Is there some reference where this thing is defined from the purely categorical POV (and where, for example, the definition is stated for a *transfinite* chain $\alpha\to FS(\cal C)$)?

Comment: What is the "small object argument"?  What is the problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: The small object argument is (roughly) the following statement; let $J\subseteq \hom(\cal C)$ be a set of morphisms, if the domains (or codomains, I never remember) of arrows in $J$ are small (i.e. $\hom(X,-)$ commutes with filtered colimits for each $f\colon X\to Y$ in $J$) then $({}^\perp(J^\perp), J^\perp)$ is a factorization system on $\cal C$.

Answer (score 2):

I still can't see what the question is.   You seem to be asking when a *pre*factorisation system (an orthogonal pair $(E,M)$ in which both sides are closed in the Galois connection) actually admits factorisation.   You need some finite limits or colimits for this, not just filtered ones. [Example 5.7.10](http://paultaylor.eu/prafm/html/s57#r5.7.10) in my book (*Practical Foundations of Mathematics*, CUP 1999) shows a poset with six points that is not a lattice together with a prefactorisation system that is not a factorisation system.   It is followed by a version of the special adjoint functor theorem that shows how to get a factorisation system.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look; I'm referring to [this](https://ncatlab.org/joyalscatlab/published/Weak+factorisation+systems#small_object_argument) construction, and in particular to thm. 1 and corollary therein. Smallness assumptions on the domains of maps in $J$ ensure that the prefactorization system is indeed a factorization. The question is: I expect the same construction to be studied in the case of multiple (even transfinite) FS on categories. Has this been done before, in the naive way I described above?

Comment: @FoscoLoregian   Forget "smallness" and "transfinite" - they are part of the superstition of set theory.  The notion of a factorisation system on a category is finitary and you need finitary structure such as pullbacks to make it work.  If you're interested in multiple factorisation systems on a category then why not start with the problem that I gave you, namely finding out whether they form a modular or distributive lattice.